# assigning different values to the same class selector in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not sure what terminology to use here, but is there a way to assign different values to multiple different elements when selecting them by their class?  In the code below, I'd like to have all  elements with class="out" to be populated with the value of their neighboring (cousin) input element with the class "value".  (in truth, it's more complicated, but that's my simplified question).

```
<tr>
   <div id="samp1">
     <td>Sample 1</td>
     <td><input class="value" type="number" value="100"></td>
     <td><span class="out"></span></td>
   </div>
</tr>
<tr>
   <div id="samp2">
     <td>Sample 2</td>
     <td><input class="value" type="number" value="200"></td>
     <td><span class="out"></span></td>
   </div>
</tr>
```

I can get the value of the cousin by something like this:

```
$('.out').closest('div').find('.value').val();
```

but I'm at a loss for how to assign those values relatively to each of the  elements without having that value being the same across the multiple elements ... for instance:

```
$('.out').html($('.out').closest('div').find('.value').val());
```

gives me a value, but it assigns the first value in the document (in this case, the value from the input in #samp1) to ALL of the spans, including the span in #samp2.

I feel like I'm looking for something along the lines of

```
$('.out').html($(this).closest('div').find('.value').val());
```

but that obviously doesn't work...
Thanks for any help.

Comment: YOu cannot have a `div` hold the `td` (table data) elements!

Comment: ok thanks.  I only put it there to have a parent i could more easily identify... I'll just use <tr> as the parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `jQuery.each` to iterate over all your `.out` elements.

```
$('.out').each(function(){
  $(this).html($(this).closest('div').find('.value').val());
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

> Description: A generic iterator function, which can be used to
>   seamlessly iterate over both objects and arrays. Arrays and array-like
>   objects with a length property (such as a function's arguments object)
>   are iterated by numeric index, from 0 to length-1. Other objects are
>   iterated via their named properties.

Comment: thanks very much.  that did the trick.  I'll delete the div and make it closest('tr') to make the HTML valid.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.out').each(function(index, elem) {

    var out = $(elem);
    out.html(out.parent().parent().find('.value').val());

});
```

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski sure it does! :)

Comment: Yeah, ok, fixed that.  Also made it so that it will still work once the HTML is made valid.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.out').each(function(){
   $(this).html( $(this).closest('tr').find('.value').val() );
});
```

Another thing is your HTML is not valid.

You can't put `<div>` between `<tr>` tags